# Ejabberd Installation - fatal error: erl_driver.h: No such file or directory

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, erlang, xmpp, ejabberd

I have erlang installed on a normal instance unix instance on AWS.
Now I am trying to install ejabberd, however I am stuck at this particular step.

The installation steps I use are:

```
sudo ./configure --with-erlang=/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4
sudo make
sudo make install
```

However when I get to "sudo make", I get the following error:

```
/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4/bin/escript rebar compile && :> deps/.built
==> p1_utils (compile)
==> p1_cache_tab (compile)
==> p1_tls (compile)
Compiling /home/ec2-user/ejabberd-14.12/deps/p1_tls/c_src/p1_tls_drv.c
/home/ec2-user/ejabberd-14.12/deps/p1_tls/c_src/p1_tls_drv.c:23:24: fatal error: erl_driver.h: No such file or directory
 #include <erl_driver.h>
                        ^
compilation terminated.
ERROR: compile failed while processing /home/ec2-user/ejabberd-14.12/deps/p1_tls: rebar_abort
make: *** [deps/.built] Error 1
```

Not sure why this error is occurring. Erlang was definitely installed because I could check its version from the console.

I suspect there might be some configuration issues?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the ejabberd source code, the `--with-erlang` option handling does nothing to ensure that the C header files needed to correctly compile Erlang drivers and NIFs are included from the specified directory. I think this is an ejabberd build system bug.

You need to tell the configuration and make steps where to find Erlang to ensure that the C compiler searches your Erlang installation for header files. Normally you can do this by specifying `CFLAGS` explicitly as part of the `configure` step, but that won't work in this case because that variable doesn't make its way through to the `rebar` build. A different way to do this that should work in this case is to make sure your Erlang installation is found in the `PATH`:

```
export PATH=/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4/bin:$PATH
./configure --with-erlang=/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4
make
sudo make install
```

The ejabberd build system looks for `erl` and `erlc` in the `PATH` and then uses the root directory of where it finds them to look for includes files and libraries also needed for the build.

Also, note that you probably do not need to use `sudo` for either the `configure` or `make` steps, but rather only for the `make install` step.

Comment: Thanks for the replying. However, this does not work somehow. I would suspect that with proper configuration i would not need the "--with-erlang=/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4" with the ./configure command. the commands erl works on my console but I just dont understand why Ejabberd can't find it during configuration

Comment: One other thing you might try is setting the `CPATH` environment variable like this: `export CPATH=/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4/usr/include` . This makes gcc treat that path as if it were specified with `-I` on the compilation command line.

Comment: Thanks again, but it still doesnt work for me. But at least now i can configure without the "--with-erlang". However the same error remains on the "make" step

Comment: Can you make sure that the `erl_driver.h` file exists in the `/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4/usr/include` directory I'm specifying? If not, run `find /home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4 -name erl_driver.h` and use the directory where it's found to set `CPATH` instead of `/home/ec2-user/otp_src_17.4/usr/include`.

Comment: Yup, it definately exists. i used "find -name erl_driver.h" and it gave me 3 results. Thanks for the help so far. I have went on to install ejabberd on ubuntu instead of the default aws fedora instance and it now works just fine. Just wondering if you would be able to recommend a tutorial on how to implement ejabberd with an android app using the java smack library (for a whatsapp like clone)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working. As for ejabberd and android, sorry, but I can't help you there (I use Erlang in general, but not ejabberd).